# Custom product attribute doesn't display on cart and confirm mail

Tags: magento2, cart, email, custom-attributes

I need some help because I don't know how to fix this problem.

On my product, I have 3 attributes (classe, dimension, color) and I choose with a select the value.

But when I go to the cart page, the value does not display, same issue on confirm mail.

Someone have an idea to fix ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to show an attribute to cart page you just need to create **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/catalog_attributes.xml** and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="custom_attribute_name"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Then you can call the attribute like this:

```
echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('custom_attribute_name');
```

Comment: I need to create a module ? I don't understand why "classe" and "dimension" are display, even if I didn't create the module ?

Comment: The solution doesn't work...

Comment: You can see the attributes because you are in the product view. To be able to see an attribute in cart page you need to add it to the quote_item. Clear cache and check again.

Comment: But why in the cart page, i can see 'classe:' and 'dimension:' ?

Comment: These attributes are used to create simple products (variations) for the configurable?

Comment: Yes, these attributes are used to create simple products (variations) for the configurable